# Pass Multiple object types to method with single type

Tags: java

I have multiple classes with different names, but they all have the same variable names. I would like to pass them to a single method and access the variables directly. The example below only shows two but I have many more.

```
Class1{
 float x,y;
 MyArrayObj myarrayobj;//this is new'ed.
}
Class2{
 float x,y;
 MyArrayObj myarrayobj;//this is new'ed.
}

static myGenericMethod(GenericClassObj myObj){

float x = myObj.x;
float pt = myObj.myarrayobj.array[0];

}
```

Is this possible, or do I have to use "getters/setters' ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible as to access the fields, just don't mark them private. `float pt = myObj.myarrayobj[0];`.

Comment: why do you need two different classes that have same content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all of these classes share common fields, extract those fields to a superclass and make your existing classes extend that. Then your generic method takes an object of the superclass type and accesses the fields directly.

```
abstract MySuperClass{
    float x,y;
    MyArrayObj myarrayobj;//this is new'ed.
}
Class1 extends MySuperClass{
    // Class1 specific fields and methods
}
Class2 extends MySuperClass{
    // Class2 specific fields and methods
}

static myGenericMethod(MySuperClass myObj){
    float x = myObj.x;
    float pt = myObj.myarrayobj.array[0];
}
```

Make the superclass abstract (as above) if you don't want it to be instantiated.